# Add HTTP Header of a Get Call for HTML Link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have an `<a>` tag in my HTML code.
This link is going to be clicked to get a 302 redirect.
However, I want to add some HTTP header within this get call.
How can I do that?
The attribute `href` cannot be included HTTP headers.

BRs,
Ryan

Comment: It is not problem of `<a>` tag. Target page is 302 redirect . check htaccess.

Answer (score 0):

I can't get any idea why you can need this, but if I've faced such task I've done something like this:

```
$('a').click(fucntion(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
      url:$(this).attr('href'),
      headers: {'header1':'value1','header2':'value2'},
      success:function (data,status,xhr){
        //some handling code
        window.location=xhr.url;
      }
  });
});
```